# Constructing $\sqrt{n}$ as the length of a right triangle

Tags: solution-verification

I'm reading Martin Liebek's book, and he gives a construction of $\sqrt{n}$ as the side length of a triangle, but leaves the verification as an exercise. It's a bit difficult to describe the picture in full without drawing it, but the construction is:

1. We have a circle with diameter $AB$, with $D$ being a point between $A$ and $B$.
2. The point $C$ is located on the circle directly above the point $D$.
3. $D$ is chosen so that $AD = n$ and $DB = 1$.
4. The triangles $ACD$, $BCD$, and $ABC$ are right triangles.

The goal is to solve for side $CD$, which he claims is equal to $\sqrt{n}$. From the picture, it isn't immediately clear to me that $ACD$ is a right triangle, so I assume this is an assumption baked into the problem, and there isn't a way to "prove" this is the case. I'll try to apply the Pythagorean theorem to each triangle:

\begin{align*}
(AD)^2 + (CD)^2 &= (AC)^2 \\
(DB)^2 + (CD)^2 &= (CB)^2 \\
(AC)^2 + (CB)^2 &= (AB)^2 
\end{align*}
This is a system of three equations in three unknowns, so it should be solvable, but I'm struggling with the verification. To make things a bit simpler, I'll replace $AD$ with $n$, $DB$ with $1$, $AB$ with $n+1$, and define
\begin{align*}
a &= (CD)^2 \\
b &= (AC)^2 \\
c &= (CB)^2,
\end{align*}
so the system becomes
\begin{align*}
n^2  + a^2 &= b^2 \\
1 + a^2 &= c^2 \\
b^2 + c^2 &= (n+1)^2. 
\end{align*}
We substitute $n^2 + a^2$ for $b^2$ in equation (3):
$$
n^2 + a^2 + c^2 = (n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1,
$$
so, cancelling $n^2$, we get
$$
a^2 + c^2 = 2n + 1. 
$$
We substitute $1 + a^2$ for $c^2$, and cancel a $1$ to get
$$
2a^2 = 2n,
$$
so $a^2 = n$, so $a = \sqrt{n}$. That is, $CD = \sqrt{n}$.

How does this proof look?

Comment: Your proof is fine, and triangle ACD is indeed a right triangle the same way BCD is a right triangle. This is given from C being directly above D, implying that CD is perpendicular to AB.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a nice proof by applying Pythagorean Theorem.
And an alternative solution by using similarity between triangles is

$\angle ACB=90^{\circ}$ (angle in semicircle)

$\angle CDA=\angle CDB=90^{\circ}$

$\angle A=\angle BCD$

$\angle ACD=\angle B$

$\triangle CAD \sim \triangle BCD$ (AAA Similarity Theorem)

$\frac{AD}{CD}=\frac{CD}{BD}$

$\frac{n}{CD}=\frac{CD}{1}$

$CD=\sqrt n$